# Device Tree configuration i.MX6

Tags: arm, embedded, linux-device-driver, u-boot

Hy all,

I have developed my own board based on a i.MX6 from Freescale and I want to configure the device tree.
I am using this software : [Processor Expert for i.MX](http://www.nxp.com/products/software-and-tools/software-development-tools/processor-expert-and-embedded-components/software-suites/processor-expert-for-i.mx:PROCESSOR-EXPERT-IMX?fsrch=1&sr=1&pageNum=1) to generate all the pin's configurations.
The software is generating .c and .h files :

```
GPIO.c
I2C.c
...
iomux_config.c
iomux_config.h
...
```

My question is : How and where I have to implement those files in my linux kernel or in my u-boot files ? Or do I have to generate a dts file ?

Thanks in adance for your help !

**EDIT :**

Here is some of the generated files :

*iomux_config.c :*

```
#include "iomux_config.h"

/*
** ===================================================================
**     Method      :  pin_init_iomux_config (component PinSettings)
*/
/*!
**     @brief
**         This method sets registers according routing settings. Call
**         this method in user code to route desired pins into
**         peripherals. The method is useful for reinitialization HW
**         after some routing changes.
*/
/* ===================================================================*/
void iomux_config(void)
{
        configure_audmux_pins(0u);
        configure_ecspi_pins(1u);
        configure_enet_pins(0u);
        configure_gpio_pins(0u);
        configure_gpio_pins(1u);
        configure_gpio_pins(3u);
        configure_gpio_pins(5u);
        configure_gpio_pins(6u);
        configure_i2c_pins(0u);
        configure_i2c_pins(1u);
        configure_i2c_pins(2u);
        configure_i2c_pins(3u);
        configure_ipu1_pins(0u);
        configure_pwm_pins(0u);
        configure_pwm_pins(1u);
        configure_pwm_pins(2u);
        configure_pwm_pins(3u);
        configure_src_pins(0u);
        configure_uart_pins(1u);
        configure_uart_pins(2u);
        configure_uart_pins(3u);
        configure_usb_pins(0u);
        configure_usdhc_pins(2u);
        configure_usdhc_pins(3u);
}
/* END pin_init. */
```

*i2c.c :*

```
#include "iomux_config.h"

void configure_i2c_pins(uint32_t instance)
{
  switch(instance) {    
    case HW_I2C1:                       /* I2C1 */
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C1_SCL_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_CSI0_DATA09_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x04UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_CSI0_DATA09_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x03UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C1_SDA_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_CSI0_DATA08_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x04UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_CSI0_DATA08_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x03UL); 
      break;
    case HW_I2C2:                       /* I2C2 */
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C2_SCL_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_EB2_B_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x06UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_EB2_B_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x09UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C2_SDA_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA16_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x06UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA16_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x09UL); 
      break;
    case HW_I2C3:                       /* I2C3 */
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C3_SCL_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA17_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x06UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA17_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x09UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C3_SDA_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x00UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA18_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x06UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_EIM_DATA18_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x09UL); 
      break;
    case HW_I2C4:                       /* I2C4 */
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C4_SCL_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x01UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_GPIO07_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x08UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_GPIO07_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x07UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_I2C4_SDA_IN_SELECT_INPUT_WR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x01UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_GPIO08_SET(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x08UL); 
      HW_IOMUXC_SW_MUX_CTL_PAD_GPIO08_CLR(IOMUXC_BASE, 0x07UL); 
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

The others are quite identical.

Comment: `DTB` files came from `dtsi` and `dts` files, no .c files are involved. You can find the in kernel source at `/arch/arm/boot/dts`. I don't know the Processor Expert for i.MX. Try to post the content of one of those files and we can try to understand if it is using Freescale header of `U-Boot` sources.

Comment: Pinctrl is responsible for this.  You do it with a dtsi, dts.  Here is [a sample](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-sabrelite.dtsi#n313). With [pinctrl doc](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/pinctrl.txt) and [DT bindings docs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl,imx-pinctrl.txt) and various others in the same directory.  You need to translate process expert to this structure.

Comment: I have to convert the generated files with the docs you sent me?

Comment: I think is better to start form a sample, instead of translate form those files. Are you using a Freesc... whoops, NXP demo board? Which Micro?

Comment: Haha nice ! I'm using the MCIMX6U7CVM08AC (it's a Dual Lite i.MX6) on a non commercial board. But if those files are unusable maybe starting from a sample is my solution...

Comment: ok. Start form [imx6dl-pinfunc.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl-pinfunc.h) and [imx6dl.dtsi](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl.dtsi) and then a sample of a board device mapping dts, e.g [THIS](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl-riotboard.dts). BTW look at same location in your kernel source files. You can find a lot of dts examples: `find . -name "imx6dl-*.dts"`